# Google Cloud Vision Form Data Extract for handwritten text python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I have a image like this [image]

I'm trying to extract the form data like this

```
{
"comments":"nil",
"namefirst":"Jhon",
"last":"Doe",
"mf":"",
"address 1": "PICADALLY LONDON",
"APT":"103",
"City": "London",
"State":"Nil",
"DOB": "",
"AGE": 43,
"Phone Number":"+4464343",
"email":"nil",
"date":"20-03-2012"
}
```

But I'm unable to extract it like that I'm able to get the box boundaries I'm stuck here since 5 days any help would be greatly appreciated.

my code

```
items = []
lines = {}

for text in response.text_annotations[1:]:
    top_x_axis = text.bounding_poly.vertices[0].x
    top_y_axis = text.bounding_poly.vertices[0].y
    bottom_y_axis = text.bounding_poly.vertices[3].y

    if top_y_axis not in lines:
        lines[top_y_axis] = [(top_y_axis, bottom_y_axis), []]

    for s_top_y_axis, s_item in lines.items():
        if top_y_axis < s_item[0][1]:
            lines[s_top_y_axis][1].append((top_x_axis, text.description))
            break

for _, item in lines.items():
    if item[1]:
        words = sorted(item[1], key=lambda t: t[0])
        items.append((item[0], ' '.join([word for _, word in words]), words))

print(items)
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what are you getting? Also, it would be useful to see how the `response` is obtained.

Comment: Yes i'm getting the response in the x,y coordinates. I'm struggling to get the response in the above desired format

Comment: @dedObed You want me to show the response that I'm getting with the above piece of code ?

Comment: @dedObed is it possible to get the result like that ?

Comment: Can you update your question with the response that you're getting?